# Semantical Error ;The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MinLength"

Tags: symfony, validation

Using Validator I have this Error

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MinLength" in property My\testBundle\Entity\Desk::$title does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

```
namespace My\testBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* Desk
*
* @ORM\Table(name="desk")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\testBundle\Repository\DeskRepository")
*/
class Desk
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DeskComment", mappedBy="desk", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 */
protected $comments;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\MinLength(
 *     limit=3,
 *     message="Your name must have at least {{ limit }} characters."
 * )
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="symmary", type="text")
 */
private $symmary;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="note", type="decimal", nullable=true)
 */
private $note;
```

The problem is `@Assert\MinLength`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Length](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html) with min instead.

From the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/constraints/MinLength.html).

```
The MinLength constraint is deprecated since version 2.1 and will be removed
in Symfony 2.3. Use Length with the min option instead.
```

Comment: Now i have this Exception :The options "message" do not exist in constraint Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length

Comment: I want this message : message="Your name must have at least {{ min }} characters." !!!

Comment: It doesn't have an option `message` as it covers min and max. The option you need is `minMessage`. It's all in the docs.

Comment: thank you it works very well but the message is not displayed :\

Comment: Maybe you are missing `{{ form_errors(form.title) }}` in your template. It part of the `{{ form_row() }}` call but wouldn't be called if you are just using the `{{ form_widget() }}` call.

Comment: no i have {{ form_errors(form.title) }}  in my template!!                 <div>
    {{ form_errors(form.title) }}
    {{ form_label(form.title, 'Title'|trans) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.title) }}
    </div>

Comment: And you are now using min rather than limit?

Comment: yes !!!  * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     minMessage="Your name must have at least {{ min }} characters."
     * )

Comment: Update your code or ask a new question with more information. I can't really work it out purely from guess work.